# How to broadcast an event to an specific user with Pyramid and socketio

Tags: python, socket.io, pyramid, gevent

I've been looking at [gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio) and was wondering how do I broadcast to an specific user. Lets say I want to send a notification to userX when userY submits data. The examples broadcast messages to all users on a chatroom, but still can't figure out how to broadcast and event to an specific user. Do I need to create a custom Broadcast Mixin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to implement a special broadcaster, or a special room, you will need to implement your own Mixin.  I just added the 'session' attribute to the Namespace and Socket object.. on which you can set whatever information you want (it's a dictionary).  I suggest having an event that will set the nickname on, say, `self.session['nickname']`, and then a function similar to `broadcast_event()` (on the BroadcastMixin), that will loop through all the sockets, check its session to verify if the socket belongs to that particular user, and send the packet in if so.

Take a look at [the code](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/blob/master/socketio/mixins.py). It is quite simple to use. You just need to understand the Socket / Namespace relationship.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre for writing the example. I'll take a look at it. So far has been really easy to implement, thanks for all the work you've put on this project.